# How to use array.includes in a promise in React Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

The problem I am really having is `.includes()` method is behaving erratically. I am using it to check if a user entered word is a valid word, like `allWords.includes(userWord)`. It usually returns `false`, regardless of inclusion of word. allWords is like 12,000 elements or so, I think I need to call it asynchronously.

A simpler version in codesandbox works, but it's always returning `false` in my react program. I am still new to TS, and async programming. Planning to read a book on it, but want to finish this darn program first.

Here is my async function

```
//helpers.ts
export async function validateGuess(guess: GuessCharacter[]): Promise<boolean> {

  async function includesPromise(array: string[], word: string) {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      resolve(array.includes(word));
    });
  }
  
  //each letter of word is in an object
  let word: string = '';

  for (let character of guess) {
    word += character.value;
  }

  return includesPromise(allWords, word).then((result) => result);
}
```

Here is where it is called

```
/// index.ts
  function handleEnterPress() {
    validateGuess(gameState.guesses[gameState.guessCount]).then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        dispatch(ActionKind.Enter);
      } else {
        console.log('Not in word list');
      }
    });
```

I've also tried

```
  async function handleEnterPress() {
    let status: boolean = await validateGuess(
      gameState.guesses[gameState.guessCount]
    );
    if (status) {
      dispatch(keyAction.Enter);
    } else {
      console.log('Not in word list');
    }
  }
```

All help is appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: *"...allWords is like 12,000 elements or so, I think I need to call it asynchronously..."* You don't, it doesn't do any good, and 12,000 is nothing to worry about in any case. You still tie up the main thread. Promises don't make anything except promise reactions asynchronous, and asynchronous != multi threaded. Your code still runs on the main thread, and in fact, still runs synchronously (it's only the call to your result callback that's [slightly] asynchronous).

Comment: Also note that `.then((result) => result);` is pointless, it literally does nothing (except introduce an extra async tick).

Comment: Two things there:

1. What doest gameState.guesses contain? 
2. `gameState.guessCount` should NOT be greater than `(gameState.guesses.length - 1)` or you will get an undefined value

Comment: Setting aside the issues above, I don't see any reason your promise wouldn't be fulfilled with the correct `true`/`false` value, and you seem to be consuming the promise correctly. That should work (and [does on the TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzAvRm)), although again the promise aspect of it is unnecessary.

Comment: I suggest deleting the question, removing the unnecessary promise parts, and if you're still getting inconsistent results, post a new question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, et. al. Thanks for your help. I wrote a snippet, without the promise and it worked. I could only get the snippet to run with a react component, so I couldn't build it out using the useReducer hook and dispatch, as the program actually is. I will take the original code, without the promise, and create in a new question and delete this Q. gameState.guessCount is always > 0. Thanks for the feedback, i see that my .then() callback is pointless!

Answer (score -1):

Your logic looks OK.

A couple of things there:

1. What does `gameState.guesses` contain? For your logic to work it should be an `array` of `objects` with a property called `value` which should be an iterable
2. If gameState.guesses[i] is a string you should NOT do `word += character.value` but:
   `word += character` instead
3. `gameState.guessCount` should NOT be greater than `(gameState.guesses.length - 1)` or you will get an undefined value
4. You don't need to use an async operation there once it's going to be an in-memory operation, you won't be doing it any faster nor going to free processing time for other tasks.

Comment: This would be a fine answer without the first sentence. The async stuff does *not* look OK.

Comment: It's also really a series of comments, not an answer, most of which have already been made (by you [Marco] and me :-) ). The question can't be *answered* in its current state; there are too many unknowns, and reasonable assumptions about them make the code work (or not; your `.value` assumption above is worth noting in a comment -- but if `guesses[i]` is a string, the whole `for-of` is pointless).

Comment: @Bergi OP already told he is knew to the language and async operations. He's async stuff does not look good but it works altough, so he's asking why his code always returns false, which is a logic problem not an async best practices problem.

@T.J Crowder if `guesses[i]` is a string than **it is an interable**, which does not makes it pointless, there are better ways of doing it, but does not necessarily compromise the objective, so it works. The question is about what's the goal of OP's code in each part of it in order to find the bug and **NOT** about how good OP's code looks like.

Answer (score -2):

The main issue is that you think this line returns `result`. It doesn't. It returns the unresolved promise. When the promise gets resolved (because you added a `.then()` the result is passed in... but then it's lost.

```
  return includesPromise(allWords, word).then((result) => result);
```

You could await that to get the value out of the promise. Best to not mix async/await and .then()/.catch().

EDIT: ... and the comments from others are all valid as well.

Comment: While that part is wrong, it doesn't affect the fact that the code actually does work. It's just unnecessary, it doesn't make anything fail.

Comment: Ah, right. That promise gets resolved in validateGuess().then(). Nevermind...